# JWT creation is missing the signature portion

Tags: c#, encryption, jwt

I'm trying to generate a JWT to use as an Authorization header for a HTTP request.

This is happening in C#, using the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` package from Nuget. My code for it is as follows:

```
byte[] certByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String("CertificatePrivateKeyPlaceholder");
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certByteArray, "MyPassword");
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

var descriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
 {
     Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
     {
         new Claim("Issuer", "MyIssuer"),
         new Claim("Audience", "MyAudience")
     }),
     EncryptingCredentials = new X509EncryptingCredentials(certificate),
     SigningCredentials = new X509SigningCredentials(certificate, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature, SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest),
 };

 var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken();
 string stringToken = "bearer " + tokenHandler.WriteToken(token)
```

At the end `stringToken` looks like a JWT, but it is of the format `aaaa.bbbb.` and it appears that the signature portion (after the second `.` is missing)

Any pointers as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Oh damn, what an oversight on my part. Thanks! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the descriptor as a parameter to `CreateToken`:

```
var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(descriptor);
```